# Is it worth having an "Interactive Fiction" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have asked two questions about puzzles from a very old interactive fiction game called Praser 5 by Andrew Plotkin. They were very hard puzzles with good answers.

There are quite a few old interactive fiction games like this that were never popular enough to have walkthroughs but which have great puzzles. I could see myself and possibly others asking more questions from these games.

Is it alright to use an interactive fiction tag (I can't create tags)? If not, what tag should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're pulling out particular puzzles from interactive fiction games, I suggest treating the puzzle as its own entity - use the tags appropriate for that puzzle, ignoring the fact that it was part of a game.

Because we can't actually make an interactive game puzzle on puzzling.SE, I don't think the need for an interactive fiction tag is justified.

Comment: Er, tags don't have to mean "this question is an X", they usually mean "This question is about X".

Comment: @yamikuronue I agree completely, but any question about a puzzle from an interactive fiction game can be extrapolated to be a separate entity for which the IF tag would not apply. If the question wasn't about a puzzle in the IF game, and just about the IF game in particular, then I don't think the question would belong on puzzling.se